# Which library should be used to delete files from a specific directory using C#?

Tags: c#, command-line, delete-file

I would like to do a command-line application that will delete files from a specific directory using C# to code it, but I need a library that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.IO.File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) namespace you can see as below

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\"),
              delegate(string path) { File.Delete(path); });
```

or

```
using System.IO;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dirname\");
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
  File.Delete(filePath)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.IO.File.Delete`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

For a complete app, you will probably also want to look at `System.IO.Directory`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory

Answer (score 1):

[`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) is the class that contains a `Delete` method to delete a file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)?